# Want to drop a View onto another View in android

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, listeners

Hey Friends help me to achieve the objective. I am newbie to the android development and the only thing I want to do is that I am trying to drag a button and drop it onto the other View(i.e RelativeLayout) the very first thing I have done the code for the drag.

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_map,container,false);

    button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(button1);

            v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
            return true;
        }
    });


    button1.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                    // Do nothing
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");

                    // Do nothing
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DROP event");

                    // Do nothing
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(button1);

                button1.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, button1, 0);
                button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

but the second thing I don't have Idea to do.. that is I want to drop it onto the RelativeLayout but the RelativeLayout can only allow one button to be drop on it.

Answer (score 0):

You missing the point of DragLiatenr. DragListenr listen to event of dragging, and handle them properly, so if your RelativeLayout not register to DragEvent he can't handle them.

Actually for what you asking you just need to listen for ACTION_DROP, and return true for all the others events.

Your could should like something like:

```
final RelativeLayout container; //You need to initialize your Relativelayout here
    container.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DROP event");
                    ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v); //you must first remove view from it former container
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    container.addView(v, params); // of course you need to modify params for your need
                    return true;
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Also why you put onTouchListenr you never use?